# Rust function to combine items of a slice of iterators using a function

Tags: rust, types, iterator

I'd like to create a function which takes a slice of iterators, and combines their elements with a function. The first result would be a function of the first elements of each iterator, the second would be a function of the second elements, etc ...

Visually, vertically three iterators, to the right is the output iterator:

```
it1   it2   it3         output it
a1    b1    c1    ->    f(a1, b1, c1)
a2    b2    c2    ->    f(a2, b2, c2)
a3    b3    c3    ->    f(a3, b3, c3)
```

The following does not compile but shows the idea:

```
  pub fn combine<I, A, F, B>(iters: &mut [I], combine_fn: F) -> impl Iterator<Item = B>
  where
      I: Iterator<Item = A>,
      F: Fn(impl Iterator<Item = Option<A>>) -> B,
  {
      std::iter::from_fn(|| {
          let row = iters.iter_mut().map(|it| it.next());
          Some(combine_fn(row))
      })
  }
```

What am I missing in order to make this function work?

Comment: seems that `function` doesn't accept something like `impl Trait` as generic argument, afaik. I don't know exactly why and, just by imging, the expanded code of such a function might be explosive if it was allowed because of numbers of copies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version that works:

```rust
pub fn combine<'a, I, A, F, B>(iters: &'a mut [I], combine_fn: F) -> impl Iterator<Item = B> + 'a
where
     I: Iterator<Item = A>,
     F: Fn(&mut dyn Iterator<Item = A>) -> B + 'a,
{
     std::iter::from_fn(move || {
         let mut row = iters.iter_mut().map(|it| it.next()).flatten();
         Some(combine_fn(&mut row))
     })
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c9e054b4e0a7d1fe6d5004fb5142519c)

Key things that needed to be fixed:

- The closure passed into `from_fn` had to be annotated with `move` so that the argument `combine_fn` gets moved into the closure rather than referenced from it.
- You can't use `impl Trait` in a `Fn` trait in argument position. An alternative is to use `dyn Trait` instead (although that does imply dynamic dispatch).
- The row iterator passed into the `combine_fn` has to be flattened, otherwise the values returned would be `Option<Option<A>>` instead of `Option<A>`.
- Lifetime annotations are needed to ensure that the output iterator has a lifetime no longer than the lifetime of both the `iters` array and any references captured by `combine_fn`.

Comment: Thanks very much. Didn't occur to me that `dyn` would be a part of the solution. Just assumed that somehow I'd be able to make it accept the iterator into `combine_fn`.

Comment: considering that `dyn` can reduce the runtime performance, is it possible to achieve the same goal without using `dyn`?

Comment: @xcwang Maybe although not as ergonomically. I found [this](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/closure-accepting-an-iterator-as-a-parameter/77905) post where someone is trying to do something similar.